# XML based call flow - JBPM JPDL Alternatives

Tags: java, xml, jbpm, activiti, jpdl

I have a requirement where I have to come with a design to control the code execution flow via xml. It is a kind of state machine, where I have to move between the states.
I have used JPDL xml on JBPM 4, some 5 years before. But it looks like JPDL is no more available in the latest JBPM versions.

Basically I want something like below, (Just modeled based on JPDL)

```
<start-state name="request a purchase"> 
  <transition to="evaluating"/> 
</start-state>

<state name="evaluating"> <!-- Invokes a Java Class and based on the output make transition to next state-->
  <transition name="approve" to="purchase approved"/> 
  <transition name="disapprove" to="done"/> 
</state> 

<fork name="purchase approved"> 
  <transition to="decrement inventory" /> 
  <transition to="increment revenue" />
</fork>
.
.
.
<end-state name="done" />
```

The above can be done easily with JBPM and JPDL, but in latest JBPM, without JPDL, I am not sure how to do this.
The transition between states is based on the Java class output(Like 'evaluating' state in example) and Java class will interact with external systems.
No user interaction is involved.

I need to control the call flow from XML, because it will enabale us to cutomize heavaily for each scenario without touching the java code.
I have went through Activiti and Spring web flow, But still not very clear that the above can be achieved or not with that.

Could you please suggest some suitable framework for the above requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

jBPM now uses the BPMN2 specification rather than it's own proprietary language to define processes.  Have you considered reading up on this specification and using that instead?

Comment: I am still working on that part. Currently checking the possibility of BPMN with Activiti. But still couldnt get a proper example to follow. Trying to write some sample programs